# GUI java text and textfields opposite displayed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout, jlabel

I am new to gui in java, i spent 3
 hours trying to figure out what i have done wrong or misunderstood, i should get this:

[image]

but the text in my code is  displayed  after textfields

```
   textPanel = new JPanel();
     textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,0)); 

     fName = new JTextField( 15 ) ; 
     textPanel.add(fName);
     jlbName = new JLabel ( "Firstname" );
    jlbName.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
    textPanel.add(jlbName);

     lName = new JTextField( 15 ) ; 
    textPanel.add(lName);
    jlbName = new JLabel ( "LastName" );

    jlbName.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
    textPanel.add(jlbName);



    libNo = new JTextField( 15 ) ; 
    textPanel.add(libNo);
       libNo.setEditable(false);
    jlbName = new JLabel ( "Library Number" );

    jlbName.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
    textPanel.add(jlbName);


   add(textPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
   JButton jbtN = new JButton("Add borrower");
   add(jbtN ,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: can you be more specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are inserting the components into the panel in the wrong order. You first insert the text fields and later the labels. Do the opposite, i.e. instead of:

```
textPanel.add(fName);
...
textPanel.add(jlbName);
...
```

do:

```
textPanel.add(jlbName);
...
textPanel.add(fName);
...
```